# Pasting code from stackexchange sites loses line breaks using chrome and google doc

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, google-chrome, formatting, copy-paste

This might not be a proper place to ask the question because I found a similar one on a different site -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/pasting-code-from-stackoverflow-to-notepad-loses-line-breaks-using-ie. So please feel free to move this one over, as I don't have an account there.

I'm getting the same result, but using chrome. I.e., pasting code using chrome from stackexchange sites will lose line breaks. It affects both the chrome on my Windows 8, and chromium-browser on my XUbuntu Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic.

Since nobody care to report it, is there any workaround available?

**[UPDATE]**

Sorry, thought the problem was everywhere, but it actually **only happens in google doc**. I've collect samples from various stackexchange sites and put them in:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R-qF6-imhpR7PVpt0LGo82wpgqSAhz_2CUytxzI_xSc/edit?usp=sharing
From which you can see that formatting is lost after paste. 
I'm pasting using chrome on my Windows 8 currently.

Here is an extra sample to test pasting for:

```el
(defun my-turn-on-allout-mode-maybe ()
  "Enable `allout-mode', where applicable."
  ;; Unconditional here, but edit as desired if it turns out
  ;; that you don't actually want this for ALL modes.
  ;; (This function is called in every buffer, when the
  ;; global mode is enabled.)
  (allout-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-allout-mode allout-mode
  my-turn-on-allout-mode-maybe
  :group 'allout)

(my-global-allout-mode 1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please give a link to an example (or a few) where the issue appears [by editing your question](http://superuser.com/posts/874336/edit).